# How to dodge the blue shell in Mario Kart Double Dash

Tags: mario-kart-double-dash

My friends are intense MKDD gamers and we are very dirty when we play. Because of this we have been able to dodge red shells easily. I want to take it to next level, I want to dodge blue shell. I know this is possible because we have did it I just do not know the solid technique to get it.

Comment: If you like playing dirty, breaking on the right time might take out some other players behind you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A properly timed mushroom/boost may get you out of the blast radius.

Comment: Even if you are in first place ? I had one of friends get on a corner and was able to get the blue shell to blast off course

Comment: There is a minuscule window of opportunity, but yes, even if you are in first place (though you'd have to be in the first place, if you were being targeted by the shell). I didn't even think it was possible myself, but there are videos and guides online describing how (and showing) that it's possible.

Comment: yes, I've done it a couple times. You need a shroom and wait for that slight delay as the blue shell circles above you before it rains down.

Comment: It works with a slide-boost as well.  :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're in 1st, hit the brakes hard whenever you hear the sound of a blue shell from anywhere. If you're lucky, you'll slow down enough to let someone pass you in time, at which point you simply need to keep a short distance between yourself and the new 1st placer until they get pwned by the shell.

Try to keep out of their blast radius.

Comment: Until everybody else does the same thing...  ;)

Comment: Fair, but it's a good strategy if you don't have a mushroom - and if it works, the payoff is immense.

Answer (score 3):

I've had one where it zoomed at me just as I started up a small hill/bump, the shell missed me due to my upward movement and it instead went through the ground.  The funny part is that the shell was still visible going off into the "distance" beneath the ground.

Answer (score 3):

It's very difficult to do, but if you start up a slide-boost when you hear a blue shell coming, you can activate the boost *just* before the shell hits.  As I stated though, it's quite difficult to do, and I've only ever avoided probably a few dozen shells this way.

Answer (score 1):

I too dabble in the MKDD and have avoided countless red shells. For blue shells it is the same principle; just a smaller window of opportunity. When you hear it coming, go into a drift and achieve the blue flames. Before it comes down on top of you, release the drift and boost forward so that the shell hits the ground behind you or just flies past you off the map. I've been able to do it many times, it's just a guessing game on when the shell is going to hit you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use mini-turbo strat that Evan Pugh says, that is very common.
2. Use mushroom at correct time.
3. Use a boost panel like the one in Wario Colosseum and ram into the wall.
4. Drop out( fall out of the map)
5. Cannon(enter when the blue shell is behind you)

I hope this helps.

Comment: point 4. isn't good at all, you lost more time than been hitted by blue shell