# Is there any way to avoid the blue-shell in Mario Kart 7?

Tags: mario-kart-7

I'm sure any Mario Karter knows that horrific feelings that comes along with hearing the sound of a blue shell coming ever closer. I recall that in some of the previous games there were methods for avoiding the blue-shell (although they were difficult).

[image]

What methods, if any, exist in Mario Kart 7 for avoiding the blue-shell once I know it's coming?

Comment: [#@&*%$ blue shells](http://xkcd.com/290/) (text language warning)...

Comment: Duplicate? - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/how-to-dodge-the-blue-shell-in-mario-kart-double-dash

Comment: @RavenDreamer Nope, different game.

Comment: @MatthewRead but the racing mechanics are essentially the same, yes?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I haven't played this version but several others are different enough from each other that they'd warrant separate questions about this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right before a Blue Shell hits you, it stays stationary in the air for a split second before falling down and hitting you. Because of this, you can **use a Mushroom** to dodge one if you time it just right. This was easier to do in Mario Kart Wii than in Mario Kart 7, due to changes in the Blue Shell's mechanics, but it is still possible, as illustrated by this YouTube video.

(Of course, you could also use a Star or Bullet Bill before the impact of the Blue Shell, which would also result in your dodging it.)

Answer (score 1):

There is one way that I have dodged a blue shell before, and that is hitting it with a red or green shell. If there is a straight segment of track ahead, and the blue shell is coming, you can hit the blue shell with a red or green shell by sending it behind you a little after you hear the blue shell alarm. This works because, unlike Mariokart DS, the blue shell travels on the ground until it gets close. By timing it right and getting lucky, you can avoid being hit by the blue shell. This method may probably be easier to do than the mushroom method, because if you are more likely to get a green or red shell when in first, instead of a mushroom.

Answer (score -2):

I once dodged the blue shell in mariokart wii. all i did was use shortcuts where there is a gap below you. if your fast enough the shell will drop and will go in the gap below you instead of hitting you. in mariokart 7 you can defeat(dodge) the blue shell with these items.... bullet, star, red shell, green shell, bomb-omb, mushroom. sometimes a banana works too but unlikely.

Comment: Could you explain how those items can be used?

Answer (score -5):

No there isnt any ways to avoid it.
If you are the first of the race you will get it.
There is one solution is to press the brake that makes you go backwards.
Go backwards until you get second so that the first will get it instead of you.
When he gets it just turn the motor on full and go first again and win the race